# Failing to install certbot on debian jessie

Tags: debian, certbot

I've followed the instructions at https://certbot.eff.org/all-instructions/#debian-8-jessie-nginx but cannot install certbot:

> sudo apt-get -t jessie-backports install certbot
>
> Reading package lists... Done E: The value 'jessie-backports' is invalid for
> APT::Default-Release as such a release is not available in the sources

Hints appreciated

Comment: Using the instructions for OS releases without a package since that is probably the only thing I can do in this situation.

Comment: Same issue here. Went off of https://backports.debian.org/Instructions/#index2h2: ``deb http://ftp.debian.org/debian jessie-backports main``. Ran ``aptitude install python-certbot-apache -t jessie-backports`` after adding to /etc/apt/sources.list. Got ``E: The value 'jessie-backports' is invalid for APT::Default-Release as such a release is not available in the sources`` printed twice.

Comment: Please run "apt-get update" after changing the sources list and before installing the package.

Answer (score 7):

did you follow instructions [above that](https://backports.debian.org/Instructions/) to enable backports? You need to add

> deb http://ftp.debian.org/debian jessie-backports main

to your /etc/apt/sources.list

Comment: The error message on my end quoted above was the same after adding the line you mentioned. I don't think the problem is on Sue's end.

Comment: I couldn't comment below the main post. Thought I would try the obvious.

Comment: Fair enough. Maybe others will bring up a different fix.

Comment: I had enabled backports, so that isn't the answer.

Comment: Yes I did that . and apt-get update   I get this error

Answer (score 3):

Had the error message above.
Running apt-get update (per the instructions) after adding the jessie-backports repository solved the problem for me

Answer (score 2):

If you are using Digital Ocean, they replace the APT sources with their own mirror. You can add backports support by adding this to your `/etc/apt/sources.list`

```
deb http://mirrors.digitalocean.com/debian jessie-backports main
deb-src http://mirrors.digitalocean.com/debian jessie-backports main
```

Answer (score 1):

Add this to your `/etc/apt/source.list`

```
deb http://mirrors.digitalocean.com/debian jessie-backports main
deb-src http://mirrors.digitalocean.com/debian jessie-backports main
```

run `apt-get update` after that run

```
sudo apt-get install python-certbot-apache -t stretch
```

simple change sudo `stretch-backports` to `stretch`

Answer (score -1):

Add this to your /etc/apt/source.list

`deb http://mirrors.digitalocean.com/debian stretch main`

I am running this in a docker and jessie-backports no longer exists, and stretch-backports does not contain the files.  They have been moved to stretch

Comment: Jessie is still in LTS. Why should someone upgrade to stretch?